# Scala: passing initial NULL to foldLeft

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there a way to pass `null`to Scala's `foldLeft`and still get something else as result value?

Example:

```
def cc (str0: String, str1: String): String = {
  if (str0 == null) {
    return str1
  } else {
    return str0 + "/" + str1
  }
}

val list = List("1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt")

list.foldLeft(null)(cc)
```

This is not possible because the return value of the foldLeft is `null` in this case.

Is there a way to archive what I need?

Comment: You cold use `reduceOption` here like this: `list.reduceOption{ _ + "/" + _ }.orNull`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the type you are folding over explicit: `list.foldLeft(null: String)(cc)` or `list.foldLeft[String](null)(cc)`. The issue is that 1) `null` is inferred to have type `Null` (unless the context requires another type); 2) type inference works left-to-right, so after seeing `foldLeft(null: Null)` the type parameter of `foldLeft` is fixed to be `Null` and `cc` must have the type `(Null, String) => Null` which it doesn't.